# Issue on Connect function in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have wrote a app in Qt / C++ and trying to use connect signal/slots to interact between classes. All slot/signals are declared but I'm still not able to build the MainUI

```
MainUI::MainUI(PFramework& Framework) :
    m_Framework(Framework)
{
    m_closing = false;

    connect(this,&MainUI::RequestOpenDevice, &m_Framework, &PFramework::OpenDevice);
    connect(&m_Framework,&PFramework::OpenDeviceResult, this, &MainUI::ResultOpenDevice);

    connect(this,&MainUI::SendDisconnect, &m_Framework, &PFramework::CloseDevice);
}
```

For example the MainUI class, declared the "ResultOpenDevice" as below:

```
public slots:
   void ResultOpenDevice(PULS_mtp_error_t error);
```

All calls to slots such as PFramework, MainUI are not able to build. even if they are all declared as public slots.

```
    /usr/local/Qt-5.4.2/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qobject.h:236: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const QObject ' 
with an lvalue of type 'const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (PFramework::)()>::Object *' 
(aka 'const PFramework *') receiver, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&slot), 
                           ^~~~~~~~
```

The framework is defined :

```
class PFramework
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PulsFramework();
    ~PulsFramework();

    PulsDeviceMngr *Device;

public slots:
    void OpenDevice();
    void CloseDevice();
    void isDeviceConnected();
    void GetAvailableSpace();
```

Any idea ??

Comment: missing & as in &m_Framework? What error do you get?

Comment: `All calls to slots such as PFramework, MainUI are not able to build` - which error message do you get? What does not work as expected? Also, I assume that you are using `qt5` since you are using the [new signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) - you should consider adding the qt5 tag to the question

Comment: @Arun, thanks it fix the issue but now, I got the issue below : /usr/local/Qt-5.4.2/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qobject.h:236: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const QObject *' with an lvalue of type 'const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (PFramework::*)()>::Object *' (aka 'const PFramework *')
                           receiver, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&slot),
                           ^~~~~~~~

Comment: Does PFramework inherit from QObject? Only polymorphic types of QObject can be passed in as receivers into Qt connect

Comment: The error you're getting could be due to the type of PFramework. Could you please show us the class declaration?

Comment: @Tarod Done I have added the class

Comment: @Arun, thanks I had added the Q_OBJECT but forgot to add the inherit to Qobject in the class definition

Comment: @Seb You could answer the question and mark it as solved.

Comment: @Tarod, do I put the solution in the edit ? and how do I mark it solved

Comment: @Seb I think you can write your own answer below and after that, put the mark as solved.